# nuxt-simple-sitemap not giving me absolute URLs

Tags: nuxtjs3

I'm sure this is a daft question...so be gentle!

How do you configure [nuxt simple sitemap](https://github.com/harlan-zw/nuxt-simple-sitemap) to give a list of absolute URLs rather than relative URLs?

I'm using version 2.5 (as still using nuxt 3.4.1 - due to other dependencies).

Thanks,
Shoomon

Answer (score 0):

Big shout out to the package author Harlan (https://twitter.com/harlan_zw) who reviewed my code over his discord channel.  Turns out I had got my config wrong...should have been...

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // Recommended
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      siteUrl: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL || 'https://example.com',
    }
  },
  // OR
  sitemap: {
    siteUrl: 'https://example.com',
  },
})
```